# how to create table in mysql node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

could you please tell me why my table is not created in `mysql` database .I want to create `table` name `player` having columns name `id` `name` ,`lastname` dateofbirth (DOB).
here is my code
https://repl.it/repls/BurlywoodComplicatedParameters

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    chalk = require('chalk'),
    debug = require('debug')('app'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    path = require('path'),
    mysql= require('mysql'),
    PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host : 'myhost',
        user : 'myuser',
        password : 'xxx',
        database : 'db'
    }
});

knex.schema.withSchema('sql12252060').createTable('player', function (table) {
    console.log('table')
})


app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('dd')
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    debug(`listing to ${chalk.red(PORT)}`);

});
```

Is there any other way to create schema or table inside the `mysql` ? i used `knex.js`

Comment: This might help [https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1628](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1628).

Comment: what is way to create schema or table on `db`

Comment: you can use sequelize from NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Comment: And here is the example with express: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

Comment: I guess You heard about `knex migration`.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any other way to create schema or table inside the mysql ?**

Yes there are, you can use Sequelize with Express framework for nodejs. Pasting one example from it's docs.

NPM link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite',

  // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
  operatorsAliases: false
});

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
  }))
  .then(jane => {
    console.log(jane.toJSON());
  });
```